# How to filter out columns that are all 0s in Python?

Tags: python

I have some structures that needs to be filtered. Is there a way to do this nicely in Python?

I have an ugly way of doing this, but I want to clean it up:

```
original_header = ['a','b','c']
original_rows = [[1,0,1], [0,0,0], [1,0,0]]

processed_header, processed_rows = some_cool_utility(original_header, original_rows)

assert_equals(['a', 'c'], processed_header)
assert_equals([[1,1], [0,0], [1,0]], processed_rows)
```

Comment: How about some input test data and the code you have so far ...

Answer (score 5):

```
original_header = ['a','b','c']
original_rows = [[1,0,1], [0,0,0], [1,0,0]]

#transpose rows to get columns
columns = zip(*original_rows)

#build list which is true if the column should be kept (is not a column of all zeros)  
not_all_zero = [  any(x) for x in columns ]

#filter the lists based on columns
processed_header = [x for i,x in enumerate(original_header) if not_all_zero[i] ]
processed_columns = [ x for i,x in enumerate(columns) if not_all_zero[i] ]

#transpose the remaining columns back into rows.
processed_rows = zip(*processed_columns)

print (processed_header)  #['a', 'c']
print (processed_rows)    #[(1, 1), (0, 0), (1, 0)]
```

Note that this returns a list of *tuples* instead of a list of lists.  If you really need a list of lists, you can just `processed_rows = map(list, processed_rows)`

Answer (score 5):

Use [NumPy](https://numpy.org/)

```
import numpy as np

original_rows = np.asarray([[1,0,1], [0,0,0], [1,0,0]])
original_labels = np.asarray(["a", "b", "c"])

# Get locations where columns are all zeros.
nonzero_cols = np.any(original_rows!=0, axis=0)

# Get data only where column is not all zeros.
nonzero_data = original_rows[:, nonzero_cols]
nonzero_labels = original_labels[nonzero_cols]
```

Comment: nice to learn sth about practical applications of numpy. thanks!

Comment: if this is an operation you do on large data sets (megabytes at a time) often enough (millions/minute), then you probably *do need* `numpy`

Comment: ISTM `np.any(original_rows != 0, axis=0)` does the same as the `map`/`lambda`/`.T` combination.

Comment: Alternatively one could use the method version, but that's just a matter of style.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
>>> original_header = ['a','b','c']
>>> original_rows = [[1,0,1], [0,0,0], [1,0,0]]
>>> row_major = zip(*original_rows)
>>> filtered = [(h, col) 
...             for h, col 
...             in zip(original_header, row_major) 
...             if any(col)]
>>> header, rows = zip(*filtered)
>>> header
('a', 'c')
>>> rows
((1, 0, 1), (1, 0, 0))
>>> zip(*rows)
[(1, 1), (0, 0), (1, 0)]
>>>
```

<sub>**edit:** fixed;  the `filtered` list comprehension added an additional transpose I didn't really look at hard enough</sub>

Comment: I don't think that this is even the correct output.  I think the correct output is `rows = zip(*rows)`

Answer (score 1):

If you are not stuck with the format of the data, storing the data as a dictionary makes this much simpler:

```
original_header = ['a','b','c']
original_rows = [[1,0,1], [0,0,0], [1,0,0]]

# Restructure data into easier-to-process dict
to_dict = dict(zip(original_header, zip(*original_rows)))
print to_dict # {'a': (1, 0, 1), 'b': (0, 0, 0), 'c': (1, 0, 0)}

# Filter out keys with all-zero values
filtered_dict = {k:v for (k, v) in dictify.items()
                 if not all(x==0 for x in v)}

print filtered_dict # Output: {'a': (1, 0, 1), 'c': (1, 0, 0)}
```

Comment: You should point out that you're now storing the output as a dictionary of *columns* instead of a list of *rows* + a list of column headers.  And that it is easy to retrieve a list of rows by `zip(*filtered_dict.values())`

Answer (score 0):

The following works:

```
all_rows = original_rows[:] #make a copy
all_rows.insert(0, original_header)

all_columns = list(zip(*all_rows)) #transpose
filtered_columns = [col for col in all_columns if any(col[1:])] #remove columns that only contain 0's
filtered_rows = [list(tp) for tp in zip(*filtered_columns)] #transpose back, convert each element to a list

processed_header = filtered_rows[0]
processed_rows = filtered_rows[1:]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record:

```
def some_cool_utility(header, rows):
    data = [element for element in zip(header, rows) if any(element[1])]
    head, rows = zip(*data)
    return head, rows
```